# Dates difference in C (seconds)

Tags: c, time

I have never programmed in C and therefore it is being a real challenge to write a small piece of software which returns the difference between two dates in seconds.

Just as background information, I implemented a kind of heart beat in a Python application with updates a txt file every 15 seconds. Now I would like to create a C application that checks this txt constantly and in case the difference is greater than 30 seconds, it restarts my computer.

That is how far I went so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>


//Returns the number seconds since the last time the files has been updated
int lastUpdate() {
    struct stat attr;
    stat("watcher.txt", &attr);

    //Gets the last update in the following format: Mon Aug 13 08:23:14 2012
    //ctime(&attr.st_mtime);

    time_t lastChange = &attr.st_mtime
    time_t now = time(0)

    //No idea how to implement it :-(
    //int seconds = timediff(now, lastChange)

    return seconds;
}

//Constantly checks if application is sending heart beats in a 30 seconds time frame
main()
{
    while(1 == 1)
    {
        if(lastUpdate() > 30)
        {
            sprintf(cmd, "sudo reboot -i -p");
            system(cmd);
        }
    }
}
```

Would anyone be so nice and give some hints on how to get this working?
Thank you very much!

EDITED:
Final code working without issues:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>


//Returns the number seconds since the last time the files has been updated
int lastUpdate() {
    struct stat attr;
    stat("/home/pi/watcher.txt", &attr);
    time_t lastChange = attr.st_mtime;
    time_t now = time(0);
    int seconds = now - lastChange;
    return seconds;
}

//Constantly checks if application is sending heart beats in a 30 seconds time frame
main()
{
    sleep(120);

    while(1 == 1)
    {
        sleep(1);

        if(lastUpdate() > 30)
        {
            system("sudo reboot -i -p");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You might add `sleep(1)` in your loop to avoid hogging the CPU.

Comment: Be aware that time adjustments (e.g., DST) might cause your computer to reboot unintentionally.

Comment: Adding to moooeeeep's point - rather than looking at the date and time, you should be using a monotonic timer. Most languages (and I imaginge Python is one of them) have a function that return milliseconds since bootup. You can use this to determine how long it has been between two events, and it isn't affected by the time on your computer being set. It rolls over every so often because it is in a 32-bit int, but subtracting to find the elapsed time is still safe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're in luck! `time_t` is a number, and the timestamps are the time since the beginning of 1970  in seconds. So:

```
int seconds = now - lastChange;
```

Oh, and

```
time_t lastChange = &attr.st_mtime
```

should be

```
time_t lastChange = attr.st_mtime
```

Answer (score 1):

`time_t` is *typically* the number of seconds since Jan 1, 1970 0:00:00 [UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) ([GMT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenwich_Mean_Time) ).  So a simply subtraction will work.

```
time_t lastChange = &attr.st_mtime
time_t now = time(0)
time_t seconds = now - lastChange;
printf("%ll\n", (long long) seconds);
```

Stricly speaking, `time_t` may be some other scalar.
A portable solution is to use `double difftime(time_t time1, time_t time0);`

```
#include <time.h>
double seconds = difftime(now, lastChange);
printf("%f\n", seconds);
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to subtract the `time_t`'s but you have a problem in this line

```
time_t lastChange = &attr.st_mtime
```

because `stat.st_mtime` is of type `time_t` not `time_t *`, so you should change it to

```
time_t lastChange = attr.st_mtime
```

and then

```
return new - lastChange;
```

and also, check `stat("watcher.txt", &attr) != -1`